# Cusps and Points of Inflection

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, curves

Can cusps be considered points of inflection?

I'm getting conflicting information but my thought process is that cusps cannot be points of inflection?

Can points of inflection exist when there is a vertical tangent to the graph? Assume there is change in concavity and the function is continuous.

Comment: Is there a derivative at a cusp?

Comment: derivative doesnt exist at a cusp

Comment: So it may depend on whether smoothness is part of your definition of a point of inflection or whether you use a definition that does not require smoothness (e.g. any change between convexity and concavity). My personal inclination would be to say not.

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ to be concave down on $(-\infty,\infty)$, but rather on $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$. If we use the definition of concave down to be "A function $f$ is concave down when $f'$ is decreasing", then we can see this is not the case with $f(x)=x^{2/3}$. Its derivative, $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$, is decreasing on its domain, which is $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$. So by that definition, $f(x)$ is not concave down on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

While I agree that $x^{2/3}$ does not have an inflection point at its cusp, that doesn't mean we *can't* have inflection points at cusps. It really depends on your definition of **inflection point**. You can easily make these types of cusps appear by taking absolute values of functions. For example: $g(x)=\left| x^2-1\right|$ has cusps at $x=\pm 1$ and also changes concavity there.

[image: A graph with a change in concavity at a cusp]

Answer (score 0):

no. look at the graph of $y = x^{2/3}.$  this has a cusp at $(0,0)$ but concave down on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $(0,0)$ is certainly not a point of inflection.